# BERT details + how do you use BERT's sequence output with a Keras biLSTM model?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I am experimenting with a biLSTM model and 2 different embedding techniques (FastText, BERT) applied at 2 different levels (word, sentence) all for a binary text classification task. I'm new to the BERT ecosystem and the nuances of complex deep learning in general and wanted some advice.

My biLSTM model is in Keras:

1. How exactly do I use BERT's sequence output here? (Similar to passing weights via an embedding matrix in an embedding layer.)
2. Is it recommend to use a biLSTM model on top of the sequence output(or BERT) in the first place? Examples that I have seen show an average pooling and couple of dense layers. Is this what is meant by "fine tuning"?
3. If the biLSTM model is necessary, would it then make sense to work *only* with BERT's 768 dimension embeddings or is the regular sequence output possible?
4. When should I set trainable as False when using BERT?

Will appreciate your guidance. Happy to share more details if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library, there is a detailed demo
https://github.com/bojone/bert4keras

```
import numpy as np
from bert4keras.backend import keras
from bert4keras.models import build_transformer_model
from bert4keras.tokenizers import Tokenizer
from bert4keras.snippets import to_array

path = '/tmp'
config_path = f'{path}/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_config.json'
checkpoint_path = f'{path}/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_model.ckpt'
dict_path = f'{path}/chinese_L-12_H-768_A-12/vocab.txt'

tokenizer = Tokenizer(dict_path, do_lower_case=True)  # Tokenizer
model = build_transformer_model(config_path, checkpoint_path)  # build model

# test 
token_ids, segment_ids = tokenizer.encode('bert')
token_ids, segment_ids = to_array([token_ids], [segment_ids])

pred = model.predict([token_ids, segment_ids])
```